# Fabric - run as an a different user, but non-sudo

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, sudo, fabric

I want to do

```
sudo su - some_user
source virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2 gunicorn django-modeltranslation
```

using fabric.

If I do

```
with sudo_settings(sudo_user="some_user"):
     with prefix("source virtualenv/bin/activate"):
         sudo("pip install psycopg2 gunicorn django-modeltranslation")
```

I get

> The directory '/home/coby/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

followed by an exception with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
 status = self.run(options, args)
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
 requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
 ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
 require_hashes
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 281, in populate_link
 self.link = self._wheel_cache.cached_wheel(self.link, self.name)
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 68, in cached_wheel
 self._cache_dir, link, self._format_control, package_name)
File "/<home>/some_user/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 129, in cached_wheel
 wheel_names = os.listdir(root)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/<home>/<sudo_user>/.cache/pip/wheels/cd/07/05/fa31adf8c1d71f5979e4329601d36c883f063ed0e99e5e29fa'
```

**UPD:** `pip install psycopg2 gunicorn --no-cache-dir` works.

Comment: were you able to run the first set of command in the server without fab?

Comment: yes, I was able to run the first set of commands on the server through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

In shell you run `source` after `sudo` which is right because `source` is a shell builtin that affects the current environment.

You have to do the same with fabric: run `sudo()` and call `source` inside it, not outside.

Your current fab code is equivalent to

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate
sudo su - some_user
pip install psycopg2 gunicorn
```